# userform to search find and return data

Tags: vba, excel

I get a error (*Invalid procedure call or argument*) when trying to search and return all the data within my spread sheet. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance!!!

Code is below:

```
Private Sub PlaceValues(Index As Long)
With Me
    .txtLoggedBy.Value = CallDetails(Index).Value
    .txtCallNumber.Value = CallDetails(Index).CallNumber
    .txtDateField.Value = CallDetails(Index).DateField
    .txtTitle.Value = CallDetails(Index).Title
    .cmbOwnerField.Value = CallDetails(Index).OwnerField
    .txtDescription.Value = CallDetails(Index).Description
    .txtSolution.Value = CallDetails(Index).Solution
End With
End Sub
```

Kind regards.

CallDetails code is:

```
Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String) As Collection

Dim rng_to_search As Range
Dim rFound As Range
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim FoundItem As clsCallDetails

Set CallDetails = New Collection

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")
    Set rng_to_search = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

With rng_to_search
    'Look for the first instance.
    Set rFound = .Find(what:=NumberToFind, _
                       after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                       SearchDirection:=xlNext)
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = rFound.Address
        Do
            Set FoundItem = New clsCallDetails 'Create a new instance of the class to hold the details.
            With FoundItem
                .Title = rFound.Offset(, 1)
                .LoggedBy = rFound.Offset(, 2) 'Offset from column A by 1 column, so column B.
                .CallNumber = rFound.Offset(, 3)
                .DateField = rFound.Offset(, 4)
                .OwnerField = rFound.Offset(, 6)
                .Description = rFound.Offset(, 7)
                .Solution = rFound.Offset(, 8)

            End With
            CallDetails.Add FoundItem 'Add the class instance to our collection.
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound) 'Look for the next value.

        'Continue searching until we reach the top again.
        Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With

End Function
```

Comment: You should give more information. Edit yout question and paste the complete exception so we can see exactly where is the error

Comment: Sorry, this line gets highlighted ".txtLoggedBy.Value = CallDetails(Index).Value" not sure why

Comment: Paste the `CallDetails` code. We don't know what that method does

Comment: The callDetails code is above

Comment: I would like to search on the 'Title' column to bring up the rows that match

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: You have posted the code for Find_CallNumbers  not CallDetails.

Comment: You create a `Collection` called `CallDetails` in `Find_CallNumbers` and then try to refer to it in `PlaceValues`. But the `CallDetails` variable has gone out of scope... you need to have a variable in `PlaceValues` that accepts the return of `Find_CallNumbers` and then iterate the collection and set the textboxes and whatever. Also `PlaceValues` seems to assume that there will only be one *set* of values - so why not just return the `clsCallDetails` object ?

Comment: Just a quick one. I am trying to search on the "Title" field. At the moment, I have to put every single word within the cell to bring up a result. Is there a way there, where I can type only a word or a few words contained within that cell, which is unique and that it will bring up a result.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a variable of type Long to a function expecting a type String. Change

```
Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As String) As Collection
```

to

```
Public Function Find_CallNumbers(NumberToFind As Long) As Collection
```

Comment: Just a quick one. I am trying to search on the "Title" field. At the moment, I have to put every single word within the cell to bring up a result. Is there a way there, where I can type only a word or a few words contained within that cell, which is unique and that it will bring up a result.

Comment: Um, that is not really a quick one. Best to ask it in a separate question.